# Redshift insert a date value into a table

Tags: amazon-redshift

```
insert into table1 (ID,date)
select
ID,sysdate 
from table2
```

assume i insert a record into table2 with value ID:1,date:2023-1-1
the expected result is update the ID of table1 base on the ID from table2 and update the value of date of table1 base on the sysdate from table2.

```
select * 
from table1;
```

the expected result after running the insert statement will be

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-1-6 |

but what i get is:

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-1-1 |

Comment: the table format goes wrong

Comment: Does your database have the wrong date set?

Comment: If that INSERT works for you, you can't be using PostgreSQL. Postgres uses the standard compliant `current_date` not Oracle's `sysdate` function

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i can get expected result running in OracleDB, but not in Redshift

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name when i run select sysdate ; on redshift, it returns the current date

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle, Redshift or PostgreSQL? There is definitely no function sysdate in PostgreSQL, you should get an error. These are the functions available: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: @FrankHeikens my task is to convert Oracle sql script to Redshift syntax. the above sql works in OracleDB, but not in Redshift. I want to do the same thing on Redshift.

Comment: That's easy, use current_date

Comment: @FrankHeikens one more question, can i specify the date in 06-JAN-23 format in RS in the insert statement?

Comment: i change sysdate to current_date but i get 2022-12-21 09:37:48.92479 instead of 2023-01-06

Comment: Current_date gives you a date, not a timestamp. And if you want to use 06-JAN-23 as input, use the function to_date() to convert it to a date: SELECT to_date('06-JAN-23', 'DD-MON-YY')

Answer (score 1):

I see a few possibilities based on the information given:

1. You say "the expected result is update the ID of table1 base on the ID from table2" and this begs the question - did ID = 1 exist in table1 BEFORE you ran the INSERT statement?  If so are you expecting that the INSERT will update the value for ID #1?   Redshift doesn't enforce or check uniqueness of primary keys and you would get 2 rows in the table1 in this case.  Is this what is happening?
2. SYSDATE on Redshift provides the start timestamp of the current transaction, NOT the current statement.  Have you had the current transaction open since the 1st?
3. You didn't COMMIT the results (or the statement failed) and are checking from a different session.  It could also be that the transaction started before in the second session before the COMMIT completed.  Working with MVCC across multiple sessions can trip anyone up.

There are likely other possible explanations.  If you could provide DDL, sample data, and a simple test case so that others can recreate what you are seeing it would greatly narrow down the possibilities.